# Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status 500

Tags: laravel, notifications, pusher

In Laravel 5.8 , when i try to `listen` to a private channel (using Pusher), I get this error in console, and surprisingly, I did not find anywhere in web that talked about this error (specially first part, somewhere talked about status 500 but not helpful.) :

**Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status 500 from /broadcasting/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels.**

**Notification.php**

```
class Notification implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
       return new PrivateChannel('notif.'.$this->user->id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'Notification';
    }

}
```

**Channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('notif.{id}', function ($user, $id) {

    //return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;

     return true;
});
```

**app.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'WORKING KEY',
    cluster : "eu",
    encrypted: false,
    csrfToken: 'WORKING TOKEN',
});


window.Echo.private('notif.${id}').listen('.Notification', function (e) {

        console.log(e);

    });
```

I don't need API authorization, project is web based.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this tutorial here 
https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo/episodes/1

Make sure that u already uncomment the BroadcastServiceProvider.php inside your config/app.php files under Application Service Providers...

```
    /*
    * Application Service Providers...
    */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

so that the routing can navigate through the Channels.php.

In case if still not working then you could try add the some authentication inside the BroadcastServiceProvider.php, which is by adding the auth:api checking like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

if u are using auth for links inside your api.php route.

**#EDIT 1**

For any auth issue u can try add this line inside app/Http/Kernel.php

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
         ..other middleware groups,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],
```

To consume the auth token, as stated inside Laravel docs here :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks. I uncommented it before.. I even can listen to channels in public mode. but not in private. and about `auth:api`,  although there is not any external API in my APP , I added it. and then status code changed to 0 : `received status 0 from /broadcasting/auth ` .

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a parameter missing there, try this:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'WORKING KEY',
    cluster : "eu",
    encrypted: true,<-----
    csrfToken: 'WORKING TOKEN',
    authEndpoint: 'https://yourwebsitename.com/broadcasting/auth', <-----
});


window.Echo.private('notif.${id}').listen('.Notification', function (e) {

        console.log(e);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

adding third argument in routes/channels.php worked for me
not sure why

```
Broadcast::channel('channel', function () {

// ...

}, ['guards' => ['custom-guard']]);
```